# Empty DataFrame

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an indeed scraper that for some reason decided to stop functioning and I'm not sure why. I'm really new to this so please be patient.

Here is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time

pages = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]


titleList = []
companyList = []
locList = []
salList = []
#linkList = []
descList = []



for page in pages:
    # change URL:
    source = requests.get(
        "https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=renewable%20engineer&fromage=".format(page)
    ).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

    # print ('Page: %s' %page)

    results = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "result"})

    for jobs in soup.find_all(class_="result"):

        try:
            title = jobs.find("a", class_="jobTitle").text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            title = None
        print("Title:", title)

        try:
            company = jobs.find("span", class_="company").text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            company = None
        print("Company:", company)

        try:
            location = jobs.find("span", class_="location").text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            location = None
        print("Location:", location)

        try:
            salary = jobs.find("span", class_="no-wrap").text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            salary = None
        print("Salary:", salary)

        link = jobs.find("a", class_="jobtitle")["href"]
        if "http" not in link:
            link = "http://www.indeed.ca" + link
        print("Link:", link)

        page = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
        try:
            job_description = soup.find(
                "div", id="jobDescriptionText"
            ).decode_contents(formatter="html")
        except Exception as e:
            job_description = None
        print("job_description:", job_description)

        titleList.append(title)
        companyList.append(company)
        locList.append(location)
        salList.append(salary)
        # linkList.append(link)
        descList.append(job_description)

        print("--------")

        time.sleep(0.5)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Title": titleList,
        "Company": companyList,
        "Location": locList,
        "Salary": salList,
        #'Link':linkList,
        "Description": descList,
    }
)

print(df)
df.to_csv("indeed.csv", index=False)
```

And the error when running:
2.28.1
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Title, Company, Location, Salary, Description]
Index: []

Process finished with exit code 0

Before it would result in an excel file

Would some be able to help please?

Thank you!

I was expecting an excel file but I get an empty dataframe message

Answer (score -1):

The reason your script isn't working is due to the fact that the Indeed website blocks spiders from accessing some of their pages. The URL you are sending a GET request to, "https://www.indeed.ca/jobs" is to one of these blocked pages.

If you try running:

```
source = requests.get("https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=renewable%20engineer&fromage=").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all())
```

This will visualise the source code of the page that is telling you that you've been blocked.

To view the allowed and disallowed endpoints for spiders for any website you can visit: [www.ExampleWebsite.com/robots.txt](http://www.ExampleWebsite.com/robots.txt)

It is always advisable to check this page before building your spider because non-compliance could result in penalties.